# ClassNotFoundException com.mysql.jdbc.driver jar from exported jar file

Tags: java, mysql, jar

I have a program which I just exported and has the following code:

```
public void connectToDatabase() {

              // This will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
              try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                connect = DriverManager
                          .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/letters?"
                                  + "user=sqluser&password=sqluserpw");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot connect to DB");
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getMessage());
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e.getClass());
            }
```

It works fine when it is not exported but when I exported it to a jar file it is giving me a classNotFoundException. Any idea why?

I tried adding

```
Class-Path: \Test\lib\Connector J 8.0\mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar
```

to the manifest path but still no luck

Comment: Are you bundling dependencies with the jar?

Comment: Where is that option found? I am using eclipse

Comment: I checked and I am

Comment: Class-path entries in the Manifest are *relative URLs*, not file paths, and they are relative to the location of the JAR file containing the Manifest.

Comment: If you are using maven to build it remember to build a fat jar which will package all of your dependencies inside the jar file. Check that you export the jar file from MySQL as well when you export it to a jar file.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using maven to build it remember to build a fat jar which will package all of your dependencies inside the jar file. Check that you export the jar file from MySQL as well when you export it to a jar file.